# How to remove namespace prefix from XML response using XSD?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-namespaces

I have generated Java classes from an XSD, and in my XML responses I am getting a `ns2:` prefix which I do not need.

For example, I am getting this response:

```
<ns2:location xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/">
  <ns2:response/>
</ns2:location>
```

But the response I am expecting is as follows:

```
<location>
  <response/>
</location>
```

Comment: Where are your XML responses coming from?

Answer (score 3):

Your example shows not just a *namespace prefix* (`ns2`) declaration but also an actual *namespace* (`http://www.example.com/` for the `location` and `response` elements) as not being desired.

If you have full control over the XSD, you can remove the

```
targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/"
```

attribute from the `xs:schema` element in the XSD.  Elements of XML documents conforming to this XSD will then no longer be in any namespace, and your generated Java classes will reflect this new setting.

However, be aware that deleting (or changing) `targetNamespace` effectively changes the names of the components defined in the XSD.  Think twice about making such a change if the XSD is defined by another party or otherwise already in use by others.

Comment: Is it possible to do it without removing targetNamspace  from XSD? i ahve full control of XSD but require targetNamespace for package creation with that name.

Comment: Somewhere your XML document will have to convey that it is in the namespace specified by `targetNamespace`, but read and understand [Target Namespaces & Unqualified Locals](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-0-20041028/#UnqualLocals) to see how to get part way there while keeping `targetNamespace`.

Comment: Any help on how to remove namespace prefix and xmlns from xml response using jaxb or fasterxml provider

Comment: If [Target Namespaces & Unqualified Locals](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-0-20041028/#UnqualLocals) doesn't help and you cannot remove `targetNamespace` then you appear to be frustrated by conflicting requirements.

Comment: yea pretty much frustrated .is it supported atleast what i am trying to do ? Can i use something like jaxbxmlprovider to get around this ?

Comment: was not able to look into this issue again ,but back to it now. Any idea how to use XSLT file to do above task in XSD. any help would be appreciated as i am new to this

Comment: Please ask a new question for your new question.   Thanks.